# Fitting a standard cubic spline with R

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, splines

I'm reading a book and it talks about (standard) cubic splines, defined as:

$$
E(y) = S(x) = \sum_{j=0}^3 \beta_{0j}x^j + \sum_{i=1}^h \sum_{j=0}^3 \beta_{ij} (x-t_i)_{+}^j
$$

It then mentions that the $X'X$ matrix can become ill-condition and to overcome this a cubic B-spline can be fitted as defined by

$$
B_i(x) = \sum_{j=i-4}^i \left[ \frac{(x-t_j)_{+}^3}{\prod_{m=i-4,m \ne j}^i (t_j-t_m)} \right], \quad i = 1, 2, \dots, h+4
$$

I know how to fit both in R but I fit the standard splines somewhat manually.

For example, here I fit a spline on `voltage_drop ~ time` with knots at `(6.5, 13)`.

```
voltage_drop = c(8.33,8.23,7.17,7.14,7.31,7.60,7.94,8.30,8.76,8.71,9.71,10.26,
                 10.91,11.67,11.76,12.81,13.30,13.88,14.59,14.05,14.48,14.92,
                 14.37,14.63,15.18,14.51,14.34,13.81,13.79,13.05,13.04,12.60,
                 12.05,11.15,11.15,10.14,10.08,9.78,9.80,9.95,9.51)
time = seq(0, 20, 0.5)

# Fit a standard spline
#####################
x1 = time
x2 = time^2
x3 = time^3

x4 = (time-6.5)
x4[x4<0] = 0
x4 = x4^3

x5 = (time-13)
x5[x5<0] = 0
x5 = x5^3

m = lm(voltage_drop ~ x1+x2+x3+x4+x5)
#####################

# Fit a B-spline - 1 line
#####################
m1 = lm(voltage_drop ~ bs(time, knots = c(6.5,13)))
#####################
```

Now `m` is the model fitted using standard spline and `m1` is the one using B-splines. Is there a library that will fit the standard splines directly, without me having to deal with the extra data manipulation? This data manipulation is trivial but precisely because it is trivial I'd rather have a library do it.

The models produce the same fitted values by the way, however, the coefficients are different.

```
sum(abs(fitted(m) - fitted(m1)))
2.051692e-13
```